Why do we have different statuses for a Task?
I refactored part of the code and found an interesting case. Imagine we have the following code:
var task1 = new Task(async () =>
{
  while (true)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello from Task1");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
  }
});
task1.ContinueWith(_ =>
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hello from continue 1");
});

var task2 = new Task(() =>
{
  while (true)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello from Task2");
    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Wait();
  }
});

task2.ContinueWith(_ =>
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hello from continue 2");
});

task1.Start();
task2.Start();

while (true)
{
  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));
}

So, what are we expecting here? Probably something like this:

But in reality, we get the following result:

Since tas1 get async lambda it will not be in the Running status:

Does anyone have a clear explanation?

The .Wait() in Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Wait(); blocks your thread. Avoid using it: it's an anti-pattern that can lead to deadlocks.

The Task constructor doesn't understand async delegates. The delegate is async void. The created Task represents only the launching of the async void operation, not the whole async void operation from start to finish.
